# Argument is not optional?

Tags: ms-access, vba

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
'add data to table
CurrentDb.Execute = "INSERT INTO jscbb_dir2(ID,Lastname,FirstName, PrimA, Artea,LubNum,OfficeNum,OfficePhone,Email,LabPhone,stats)" & _
" VALUES(" & Me.Textid & ",'" & Me.TextLast & "','" & Me.TextFirst & "','" & Me.Textprima & "','" & Me.Textarea & "','" & Me.Textlabnum & _
"','" & Me.Textofficenum & "','" & Me.Textofficephone & "','" & Me.Textemail & "','" & Me.Textlabphone & "','" & Me.Textstatus & "')"

'refresh data is list on focus
jscbb_dirsub.Form.Requery

End Sub
```

Why am I getting an error on the last (Me.Textstatus)?  I know this is a low-level question, but I need another pair of eyes, I've been looking at this for over an hour.  The error is "Compile Error: Argument Not Optional"

Comment: well, what error are you getting? How can we help if you don't even tell us the problem?

Comment: Assign the execute statement to a string, and send the value of that string to the immediate/debug window so you can examine the statement you think you are executing.

Comment: What does `Debug.Print TypeName(Me.Textstatus)` say?

Comment: It says "compile error: Argument is not optional"

Comment: What is `Me.Textstatus` ?

Comment: It refers to a input field called 'stats' in the table

Answer (score 1):

Consider parameters, they will be easier to debug.

```
Dim qdf As QueryDef
ssql = "INSERT INTO jscbb_dir2(ID,Lastname,FirstName,PrimA,Artea," _
     & "LubNum,OfficeNum,OfficePhone,Email,LabPhone,stats) " _
     & "VALUES([id],[last],[first],[prima],[area],[lab]," _
     & "[office],[phone],[email],[stat])"
Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", ssql)
qdf.Parameters("id") = Me.TextID
qdf.Parameters("last") = Me.Textlast
qdf.Parameters("first") = Me.Textfirst
qdf.Parameters("prima") = Me.Textprima
qdf.Parameters("area") = Me.Textarea
qdf.Parameters("lab") = Me.Textlabnum
qdf.Parameters("office") = Me.Textofficenumbet
qdf.Parameters("phone") = Me.Textofficephone
qdf.Parameters("email") = Me.Textemail
qdf.Parameters("stat") = Me.Textstatus

qdf.Execute dbFailOnError
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Execute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb243015%28v=office.12%29.aspx) is a method, not a property. You don't use `=` between a method and its arguments, so

```
CurrentDb.Execute = "..."
```

should be

```
CurrentDb.Execute "..."
```